# Read a CSV Directly Into R as a String

Tags: r, string, read.csv

I have a CSV file that I want to read into R without making it a Data Frame. It seems like it would be quite simple but I can't figure out how to do it. I quite literally just want the CSV file to read in as it would appear in a text editor. The reason for this is I need to feed the string into an API.

Using `read.csv()` obviously won't work for this because it automatically reads in as a df.

Comment: `readLines()` ?

Comment: Side point: I have at times needed to do this, but it was for very specific needs. If there is something you need done with/to the data that you have not found a way to do through `read.csv`, forcing you to try to do the parsing yourself ... it is possible that there is a better way to do it than to try to do all of the CSV-parsing/splitting manually. If I'm close, then perhaps you can provide some context to your (underlying) problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try `readLines()`

This will read in the file with each line being a value in a vector. You'll need to then wrap that in a `paste(readLines(),collapse="\n")` to have it be a single text string that could be passed to an API.

Comment: I attempted this solution and I think it will work. However, the string output is filled with backslashes. Anyway to remove those?

Comment: Those are escaping special characters such as quotation marks. They're not really there, just something R uses to denote the difference.